# I have a config.ini file with user login details and a config read method, how do I user data from config.ini in my test case?

Tags: python, selenium, authentication

I have this `config.ini` file:

```
[login]
username = test123
```

my config reader file `config_read.py`:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

def config_reader():
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    username = config['login']['username']
    return username
```

How can I then use the `username` in my test case to type it in Username input field?

Comment: what input field are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

With selenium, what you need is send keys.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome
driver.get("Your link")
driver.find_element_by_(Xpath, Id or CSS selector of your login field).send_keys("Your username")
```

With this, you will get your username and password possibly to your login field